# Remover Todo de uma lista

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

A minha função de remover Todo está removendo apenas o primeiro Elemento que foi adicionado ao todos.

```
const handleRemoveItem = useCallback(() => {
    setTodos(todos.slice(todos.indexOf(+1)));
}, [todos]);


{todos.map((todo, index) => (
<>
    <Icon src={IconClose} onClick={handleRemoveItem} />
    <Card key={index}>
    <p>{todo.regiao}</p>
    <div>
        <p>Código do Representante:</p>
        <span>{todo.codRepresentante}</span>
    </div>
    </Card>
</>
))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou passar qual *objeto* deseja **excluir** da lista e o método correto é [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) que remove o item da lista, sendo que [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) te retorna partes de um `array` e não é o que precisa. Existe outras formas de fazer isso, mas vou seguir o seu exemplo atual:

```js
function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([
    {codRepresentante: 1, regiao: 'Região 1'},
    {codRepresentante: 2, regiao: 'Região 2'},
    {codRepresentante: 3, regiao: 'Região 3'},
  ]);
  const handleRemoveItem = React.useCallback((todo) => {
    let newTodos = [...todos];
    newTodos.splice(todos.indexOf(todo), 1)
    setTodos(newTodos);
  }, [todos]);
  return (
    <div>
      {todos && todos.map(todo => 
        (
          <div>
            {todo.codRepresentante} - {todo.regiao} { ' ' }
            <button onClick={e => handleRemoveItem(todo)}>Remover</button>
          </div>
        )
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Vlw mano, deu certo!

Comment: Se for util @PauloRobson vote como resposta da sua pergunta

Comment: Tem algum motivo para utilizar o _spread_ duas vezes na função `handleRemoveItem`?

Comment: é recomendado @LuizFelipe já vi vídeos dizendo que por algum motivo ele passa a referencia e dá problema, então é melhor sempre passar a cópia, uma vez aconteceu isso comigo também em um caso real, não conseguia entender o motivo, no momento em que fiz o `spread` deu certo ... !!!

Comment: @LuizFelipe no estado eu sempre faço assim.!

Comment: Sim, mas em `let newTodos = [...todos]` você já criou uma nova referência, então não creio que tem necessidade de se fazer duas vezes (a segunda em `setTodos([...newTodos])`), já que internamente todo o array é varrido durante o _spread_.

Comment: Bom eu fiz a alteração @LuizFelipe, mas, eu lembro que já tive problema, se eu não me engano é na parte de pegar cópias de vários `arrays`, não me lembro realmente, se lembrar eu posto.

Comment: @LuizFelipe o que mudaria na prática? eu acho que nada hiem!

Comment: Na prática nada muda, o efeito "visual" e "funcional" é o mesmo. O potencial problema é em relação à performance, a depender da quantidade de elementos, uma vez que é uma "varredura" completa no array desnecessária a mais (excluindo otimizações não estandardizadas). Claro, na prática nada muda, mas se é possível evitar uma iteração a mais, porque não, né? :)

Comment: Se você usar o modo de passagem por estado como uma função pegando o antigo pelo novo é obrigado a fazer isso @LuizFelipe então acho que depende acabei verificando em um exemplo.

Comment: Eu sei disso. Mas **nesse caso** não tem necessidade de se fazer duas vezes.

Comment: Tem alguma pontuação a mais para fazer @LuizFelipe