# Componentes React que recebem a propriedade de um objeto como conteúdo não atualizam, como lidar com isso?

Tags: javascript, react, objetos, react-hooks

Basicamente tenho um estado que é um objeto complexo e vários componentes que renderizam apenas uma propriedade dele, como a aplicação é meio grande fiz este protótipo para ilustrar:

```
//Component principal que guarda um objeto como state
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    count: 0,
    title: "generic title"
  });

  const handlerIncrementData = () => {
    const newData = data;
    newData.count = newData.count + 1;
    setData(newData);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2 onClick={handlerIncrementData}>Contador: {data["count"]}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Teoricamente toda vez que eu clicar no `h2` o valor do `count` vai ser incrementado e, de fato, checando pelo React Dev Tools, ele está sendo, porém a renderização do componente não atualiza. Aparentemente o React não atualiza componentes que só usam uma propriedade do *state*. Estou fazendo algo errado ou isso faz parte da biblioteca? Caso seja, como posso contornar esse problema?

O código funciona perfeitamente usando um tipo primitivo no lugar do `obj` como *state*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme consta na [documentação do *hook* `useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update), o React utiliza o método estático `Object.is` para determinar se dois valores são iguais. O componente só será atualizado caso a **desigualdade** entre os valores seja confirmada.

A comparação feita pelo `Object.is` é muito similar ao operador `===`. A diferença é que, para `Object.is`, dois valores `NaN` são considerados iguais e `+0` e `-0` são considerados diferentes.<sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30543212/7445826)</sup>

Desse modo, precisamos lembrar que, para o `===` (e portanto para o `Object.is` também), dois objetos são *iguais* se possuirem a mesma referência. Veja:

```js
const obj = { name: 'Foo' };
const b = obj; // Mesma referência.

console.log(Object.is(obj, b)); //=> true

// Mesmo se alterarmos em `b` (ou em `obj`), a igualdade manter-se-á:
b.name = 'Bar';

console.log(Object.is(obj, b));
```

Agora veja o que você está fazendo no seu componente:

> ```js
> const newData = data;
> newData.count = newData.count + 1;
> setData(newData);
> ```

Já deu pra ver o problema, certo? :)

Veja que você está atribuindo à `newData` a referência do objeto `data` (a atribuição de objetos não cria uma "cópia", apenas a referência é atribuída). Desse modo, você não tem um *novo objeto*, mas sim o mesmo objeto!

Portanto, mesmo que você modifique uma das propriedades do objeto `newData` (que é o mesmo que `data`), o algoritmo de `Object.is` ainda determinará que são o mesmo objeto do estado anterior (já que, como vimos, essa comparação é feita com base na referência).

Enfim, para corrigir, você deve garantir que está passando um novo objeto (isto é, de diferente referência) para a função `setData`.

Uma forma de fazer isso é utilizar o *spread operator* para espalhar as propriedades em um novo literal (conforme sugeriu a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/488628/69296)):

```
const handlerIncrementData = () => {
  const { count } = data;
  count++;

  // Note abaixo que um **novo** literal está sendo criado (portanto, diferente referência):
  setData({ ...data, count });    
};
```

Uma outra opção é utilizar o `Object.assign`, passando um novo objeto em seu primeiro argumento:

```js
const handlerIncrementData = () => {
  // Novo objeto sendo utilizado como "base":
  //                    ↓↓
  setData(Object.assign({}, data, { count: data.count + 1 }));    
};
```

Em suma: para que o componente seja renderizado novamente, você há de garantir que o valor que está passando é diferente do valor anterior (de acordo com a comparação de `Object.is`). No caso de objetos, basta assegurar que a referência é diferente.

É justamente por isso que funciona se utilizar um primitivo ao invés de objeto. Primitivos são comparados por valor; enquanto objetos, por referência.

Para saber mais sobre as diferenças sobre o *spread operator* em objetos e `Object.assign`, leia [Qual é a diferença entre Object.assign e spread operator?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/477895/69296).

Comment: resposta perfeita, muito obrigado pela atenção

Answer (score 2):

Esses dias teve o mesmo problema é uma pergunta, onde até relatei para o usuário que me perguntou sobre copiar o novo estado para o objeto, que no caso usei `spread operator`, pelo que entendo quando vai se alterar objeto(s) ou lista(s) precisa utilizar uma nova cópia do objeto e/ou lista para que o componente tenha essa nova realidade ou atualização da informação, **exemplo**:

---

```js
//Component principal que guarda um objeto como state
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({
    count: 0,
    title: "generic title"
  });

  const handlerIncrementData = () => {
    let { count } = data;
    count ++;
    setData({...data, count});    
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2 onClick={handlerIncrementData}>Contador: {data["count"]}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

<sup>Referencias:</sup>

- [Using the spread operator in React setState](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/using-the-spread-operator-in-react-setstate-c8a14fc51be1)
- [Updating an object with setState in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638938/updating-an-object-with-setstate-in-react)
- [Remover Todo de uma lista](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/487988/remover-todo-de-uma-lista)

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu to fazendo uma aplicação meio grande e demorei pra perceber que alguns componentes não tavam funcionando, ja tava com medo de ser tarde demais pra mudar algo, enfim, valeu mesmo.